# Time Series from different variables

Tags: python, variables, time-series, append

I am trying to create a variable that display how many days a bulb were functional, from different variables (Score_day_0).

The dataset I am using is like this one bellow, where score at different days are: 1--> Working very well and 10-->stop working.

What I want is to understand / know how to create the variable Days, where it will display the number of days the bulbs were working, ie. for sample 2, the score at day 10 is 8 and day_20 is 10 (stop working) and therefore the number of days that the bulb was working is 20.

Any suggestion?

Thank you so much for your help, hope you have a terrific day!!

| sample | Score_Day_0 | Score_Day_10 | Score_Day_20 | Score_Day_30 | Score_Day_40 | Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sample 1 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 8 | 10 | 40 |
| sample 2 | 3 | 8 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 20 |

I've tried to solve by myself generating a conditional loop, but the number of observations in Days are much higher than the number of observation from the original df.

Here is the code I used:

```
cols = df[['Score_Day_0', 'Score_Day_10....,'Score_Day_40']]
Days = []
for j in cols['Score_Day_0']:
    if j = 10:
        Days.append(0)   
for k in cols['Score_Day_10']:
    if k = 10:
        Days.append('10')
for l in cols['Score_Day_20']:
    if l = 10:
        Days.append('20')
for n in cols['Score_Day_30']:
    if n = 105:
        Days.append('30')
for n in cols['Score_Day_40']:
    if m = 10:
        Days.append('40')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your looking for the first column label (left to right) at which the value is maximal in each row.

You can apply a given function on each row using [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1`:

```
df.apply(function, axis=1)
```

The passed function will get the row as Series object. To find the first occurrence of a value in a series we use a simple locator with our condition and retrieve the first value of the index containing - what we were looking for - the label of the column where the row first reaches its maximal values.

```
lambda x: x[x == x.max()].index[0]
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(d0=[1,1,1],d10=[1,5,10],d20=[5,10,10],d30=[8,10,10]))
#    d0  d10  d20  d30
# 0   1    1    5    8
# 1   1    5   10   10
# 2   1   10   10   10
df['days'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x == x.max()].index[0], axis=1)
df
#    d0  d10  d20  d30 days
# 0   1    1    5    8  d30
# 1   1    5   10   10  d20
# 2   1   10   10   10  d10
```

Comment: Hi Cybe, Thank you so much for your response and comments. They are very helpful to understand how I may use it!!! thanks.

I have tried what you say, but it rises the following error:

index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0. 
 I also tried to fill the potential NaN ( previously treated) with zeros, but rise the same error. Finally I tried to create first, the days variables as a empty list and second, fill the array with 0. None of them worked. do you know what could be the potential solution? Thank you in advance

Comment: Sound like your data includes lamps who are still living :) Then x[x==10] will return an empty series since there is no field containing the value 10.

Comment: Edit my answer to find the max value of each, which should handle your exception. But notice that this way the "days" columns will contain also column labels of values below 10. If you plan to have a more complex value in the "days" column, like. It's better practice to define a separate function using "def …(): …" instead of this inline lambda construction.

Comment: Thanks cybe, actually works very well and I  was able to create a new feature!!! thanks a lot